# Spring boot - running check on every request and storing objects for lifecycle

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a scenario where I need to run a few db checks at the start of every web request, and in the case of success I need to store objects for use later in the request by the controller, or in the case of failure I need to render an error page.

A very similar real world example would be a SaaS app checking and loading the account based on a vanity url, then storing the account for use by controllers to avoid multiple db requests.

What are the best ways to achieve this in a Spring boot app? I have experimented with Filters but I think an Interceptor might be better at the task, that covers running the check but what about storing the objects for later use? Is there a request lifecycle context of some kind that I can store against?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spring supports `request` scope for beans](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-request). You can use them for storing data used during request execution.

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly what I was looking for, simple and does the job :)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, best way I've done similar stuff is through `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`.

Basically imagine you have a custom type, let's call it `UserContext` where you store the information that's needed for the request. And you have a `UserContextService` let's say that has a method `getUserContext(HttServletRequest)`, that is used to retrieve the context based on the request, from which you can call your database based on whatever request parameter/header/path-variable, etc. You can refine that as you need. But based on this simple assumptions, you can have a controller that looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/some/url")
public SomeResponse someMethod(UserContext userContext, ...) {
    //do something here with UserContext
}
```

The way that Spring will inject this UserContext into your controller would be with a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` like this:

```
@Component
public class UserHandlerMethodArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Autowired
    UserContextService

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterType().equals(UserContext.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)webRequest.getNativeRequest();
        UserContext userContext = userContextService.getUserContext(req);
        if (userContext != null) {
            return userContext;
        } else {
            return WebArgumentResolver.UNRESOLVED;
            //Or throw exception
        }
    }
}
```

That you'll register by overriding the `WebMvcConfigurer.addArgumentResolvers` method in your `WebMvcConfigurer` bean/config-class.

This mechanism is the same used by `@PathVariable`, `@RequestParam`, etc...

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, I'm a little against injecting it into each and every method though, although I concede that may ultimately be more expressive and testable.. the method I've taken is to store it in a request bean and add helper methods to my base controller which all other controllers inherit from.

Comment: It will only happens where it needs to happen( i.e. Where you declare the parameter), just like any other url param or path variable, plus Spring is already full of injection and reflection. Your solution seems OK although has some coupling and boiler plate that could be avoided by this method.